# scaling features for LASSO variable selection

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, feature-scaling

I am interested in performing LASSO regression for the purpose of variable selection. The response variable is categorical (3 classes) and most of the predictor variables are categorical. Most predictor variables range from  0, 1, 2. Some categorical variables range from 1-6. In addition, there are 3 numerical variables ranging 0-8, 0-13, and 0-1000. When I scale this 3rd numerical variable (0-1000), I get the range to be 0-46. My question is how close do the ranges need to be in order to run the LASSO model? I have ranges 0-2, 1-6, 0-13, and 0-46. I am using R's scale function which uses the formula (x-mean)/sd. Do you know of any other functions/formulas that will bring the ranges closer together in order to run LASSO?

Comment: Are you using the `glmnet` package in R? If so it will by default handle the scaling for you.

Comment: yes, `glmnet`. thank you!

Comment: I would like to re-visit this question. After LASSO, I am running the same data in logistic regression, random forest, and XG Boosted. Depending on the results, I may run SVM and NN. All in R. Will I need to rescale the continuous variables in this data? If so, scaling them will result in a range of 0-46 for one of them (the others specified in the OP). Most variables are categorical with ranges of 0-2, 0-4. Won't the 0-46 still be too big for the categorical variables? If so, how can this be resolved?